# I keep getting a message "NetworkManager "Activation failed for connection ..." my old router name

Tags: networking, 20.04

I changed my wireless router out. The new router works just fine and everything connected to it works fine. My computer is hardwired to the new router, just like the old one.

All day long I get messages from what looks like the NetworkManager "Activation failed for connection". I also get another message wanting a password for the old router, and it gives its name.

Where do I find the source file that contains the routers Ubuntu thinks it is connected to? It must still contain the old router name and can I safely modify it to delete the old router without making the OS unstable?

Comment: Is there a connection listed for the old router in the network manager gui? If so, try deleting it.

Comment: Tried this after your comment. Appears I have the "network manager gui" not included in Ubuntu problem that seems to be common. This problem seems to extend to displaying the settings menu as well. Hopefully someone will find a fix for this. I've run into other problems in the past that a gui would have been handy to solve. Regarding the driver, I don't want to poke around getting a driver on a network that is running well. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All prior connections are listed in: `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. You may safely remove any or even all prior listings. As an example:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR55.nmconnection
```

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

You should be all set.

Comment: I took your suggestion and located my old network in the .../system-connections directory. I deleted those files and rebooted as you said. The messages appear to have stopped. Thank you for pointing me to the answer. I have used this site in the past to find answers to problems. I must tell you that it is a great asset to have people like you and a site like this tot help the less experienced of us solve our problems. I learn a lot from it each time. Thanks Chili.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.